# How to add Loki to Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki

I have deployed Grafana in one of our Kubernetes clusters, let's say Cluster-01. I also have another Kubernetes cluster, let's say Cluster-02. Grafana, Loki & Prometheus are installed in Cluster-01 and I need to add Loki Data Source which is deployed in Cluster-02 to Grafana which runs in Cluster-01. I have installed Loki in Cluster-02 using Helm.

```
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts

helm install loki grafana/loki --version 5.0.0
```

But when I add Loki Data source in Grafana which is in Cluster-01, it gives the below error.

```
Loki: Cannot connect to Loki. 400. Authentication to data source failed
```

I also changed the loki-gateway service to loadbalancer

```
loki-gateway                                      LoadBalancer                                10.0.3.61                                  Some-IP-here                                http:80►30947                                                 32m
```

Comment: How are you adding Loki (deployed in a different cluster) as a data source to Grafana?

Comment: From the Grafana Portal. Add > Data Source

Comment: And what endpoint you are using for Loki?

Comment: The Public IP address. I changed the service from ClusterIP to LoadBalancer

Comment: So basically my approach is correct or wrong